# What do verbs missing their -る mean?

Tags: verbs, renyōkei

When I read a light novel, sometimes I see some weird verb that does not have る like it's supposed to. For example, I see 越え instead of 越える, or 抱え instead of 抱える.

From the first page of 生徒会探偵キリカ:

> クラブの数は三百を**越え**、体育会系も文化系も全国大会常連クラスの部をいくつも**抱え**。

Comment: Could you show example sentences?

Answer (score 1):

This usage is called 連用中止法. It is used when a sentence follows without being completed. And a verb before comma changes to continuous form. For example, 彼はそのパーティで歌を歌い、踊りを踊った(He sang songs and danced).

Comment: this call Suspended form right? so verb that i show in example you have to delete る for る verb ? to make suspended form

Comment: No, it isn't suspended form but continuous form(masu form). 越え is continuous form of 越える and 抱え is continuous form of 抱える.

Comment: is that so?thank for answer i'm think i get it now

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure of suspended form. Is it plain form(dictionary form)?